# How to say that you are not a part of a line (queue BrE) and you are just watching or checking?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider there is a line of people getting their food from different options they have in front of them. You want to check what are the food options and someone in the line, whose immediate neighbor to your position, thinks that you are there to pick something and may feel bad about it. How do you say I am not here to pick something. I would say

> I am just watching (the food).

Is that the correct way to say that or does it convey the same meaning? Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you said to me:

> I am just watching the food.

the logical response would be "Why?", or the humorous one "Are you expecting it to go somewhere?".

*look* or *check* would be better verbs. They don't involve taking anything.

> I am just **looking/checking** to see what menu options there are.